Apache Camel OPC UA Client failed to load key caused by DerValue.getBigIntegerInternal, not expected 48
I'm trying to connect Apache Camel OPC UA Client (Milo) to OPC UA Server (Prosys OPC UA Simulation Server).
I'm using a .der certificate already created and trusted by UaExpert client.
My camel route is:
from("milo-client:opc.tcp://Bxxxxx3:53530/OPCUA/SimulationServer?
node=RAW(ns=3;s=testCamel)&samplingInterval=2000&keyStoreUrl=file:C:\\Users\\xxxx\\.prosysopc\\prosys-opc-ua-simulation-server\\PKI\\CA\\certs\\53B3D0C25BDF54A5A987F45296611B22xxxxxx.der").log(">>> ${body}");

But I'm getting the following error:
2024-04-03 16:28:45,979 main INFO - [o.a.c.c.m.c.i.SubscriptionManager] - Failed to connect
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load key
        at org.apache.camel.component.milo.client.MiloClientConfiguration.setKey(MiloClientConfiguration.java:474) ~[camel-milo-3.22.1.jar!/:3.22.1]
        at org.apache.camel.component.milo.client.MiloClientConfiguration.mapToClientConfiguration(MiloClientConfiguration.java:452) ~[camel-milo-3.22.1.jar!/:3.22.1]
        at org.apache.camel.component.milo.client.MiloClientConfiguration.newBuilder(MiloClientConfiguration.java:421) ~[camel-milo-3.22.1.jar!/:3.22.1]
        at org.apache.camel.component.milo.client.internal.SubscriptionManager.performConnect(SubscriptionManager.java:692) ~[camel-milo-3.22.1.jar!/:3.22.1]
        at org.apache.camel.component.milo.client.internal.SubscriptionManager.performAndEvalConnect(SubscriptionManager.java:609) [camel-milo-3.22.1.jar!/:3.22.1]
        at org.apache.camel.component.milo.client.internal.SubscriptionManager.connect(SubscriptionManager.java:604) [camel-milo-3.22.1.jar!/:3.22.1]
        at org.apache.camel.component.milo.client.internal.SubscriptionManager.<init>(SubscriptionManager.java:574) [camel-milo-3.22.1.jar!/:3.22.1]
        at org.apache.camel.component.milo.client.MiloClientConnection.init(MiloClientConnection.java:59) [camel-milo-3.22.1.jar!/:3.22.1]
        at org.apache.camel.component.milo.client.MiloClientConnection.checkInit(MiloClientConnection.java:76) [camel-milo-3.22.1.jar!/:3.22.1]
        at org.apache.camel.component.milo.client.MiloClientConnection.monitorValue(MiloClientConnection.java:94) [camel-milo-3.22.1.jar!/:3.22.1]
        at org.apache.camel.component.milo.client.MiloClientConsumer.doStart(MiloClientConsumer.java:56) [camel-milo-3.22.1.jar!/:3.22.1]
        at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:113) [camel-api-4.4.0.jar!/:4.4.0]
        at org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:126) [camel-api-4.4.0.jar!/:4.4.0]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.startService(AbstractCamelContext.java:3075) [camel-base-engine-4.4.0.jar!/:4.4.0]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager.doStartOrResumeRouteConsumers(InternalRouteStartupManager.java:408) [camel-base-engine-4.4.0.jar!/:4.4.0]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager.doStartRouteConsumers(InternalRouteStartupManager.java:325) [camel-base-engine-4.4.0.jar!/:4.4.0]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager.safelyStartRouteServices(InternalRouteStartupManager.java:211) [camel-base-engine-4.4.0.jar!/:4.4.0]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager.doStartOrResumeRoutes(InternalRouteStartupManager.java:144) [camel-base-engine-4.4.0.jar!/:4.4.0]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStartCamel(AbstractCamelContext.java:2799) [camel-base-engine-4.4.0.jar!/:4.4.0]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStartContext(AbstractCamelContext.java:2480) [camel-base-engine-4.4.0.jar!/:4.4.0]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStart(AbstractCamelContext.java:2435) [camel-base-engine-4.4.0.jar!/:4.4.0]
        at org.apache.camel.spring.boot.SpringBootCamelContext.doStart(SpringBootCamelContext.java:43) [camel-spring-boot-4.4.0.jar!/:4.4.0]
        at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:113) [camel-api-4.4.0.jar!/:4.4.0]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.start(AbstractCamelContext.java:2040) [camel-base-engine-4.4.0.jar!/:4.4.0]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:212) [camel-core-engine-4.4.0.jar!/:4.4.0]
        at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.start(SpringCamelContext.java:119) [camel-spring-4.4.0.jar!/:4.4.0]
        at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.onApplicationEvent(SpringCamelContext.java:151) [camel-spring-4.4.0.jar!/:4.4.0]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:185) [spring-context-6.1.4.jar!/:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:178) [spring-context-6.1.4.jar!/:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:156) [spring-context-6.1.4.jar!/:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451) [spring-context-6.1.4.jar!/:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:384) [spring-context-6.1.4.jar!/:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:981) [spring-context-6.1.4.jar!/:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:627) [spring-context-6.1.4.jar!/:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) [spring-boot-3.2.3.jar!/:3.2.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) [spring-boot-3.2.3.jar!/:3.2.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) [spring-boot-3.2.3.jar!/:3.2.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) [spring-boot-3.2.3.jar!/:3.2.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) [spring-boot-3.2.3.jar!/:3.2.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) [spring-boot-3.2.3.jar!/:3.2.3]
        at com.xx.fileservice.FileserviceApplication.main(FileserviceApplication.java:24) [!/:?]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[?:?]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:91) [filetransferservice.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:53) [filetransferservice.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:58) [filetransferservice.jar:?]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: DerValue.getBigIntegerInternal, not expected 48
        at java.base/sun.security.util.DerValue.getBigIntegerInternal(DerValue.java:633) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/sun.security.util.DerValue.getIntegerInternal(DerValue.java:594) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/sun.security.util.DerValue.getInteger(DerValue.java:590) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/sun.security.util.DerInputStream.getInteger(DerInputStream.java:126) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:2014) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/sun.security.util.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:221) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1473) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.camel.component.milo.KeyStoreLoader.load(KeyStoreLoader.java:114) ~[camel-milo-3.22.1.jar!/:3.22.1]
        at org.apache.camel.component.milo.client.MiloClientConfiguration.setKey(MiloClientConfiguration.java:472) ~[camel-milo-3.22.1.jar!/:3.22.1]
        ... 47 more


issue resolved generating new self signed certificate and trust it on Industrial OPCUA Server. if somebody is interested to parameters setting go to
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78651122/how-to-get-tagname-and-values-by-using-apache-camel-opcua-milo-client
