How to get tagname and value by using Apache Camel OPCUA Milo Client
I have an architecture IIoT with an Industrial Gateway OPC Server that exposes tags by OPCUA protocol.
My first target is to print tags with values by using Apache Camel OPCUA Milo client.
As technologies to test the behavior I used the following:

Spring Boot app with Apache Camel OPCUA Milo client 3.22.2 LTS version

I'm able to connect Apache Camel OPCUA Milo Client to Industrial Gateway OPC Server with self signed certificate by the following source endpoint:
milo-client:opc.tcp://127.0.0.1:49310?
keyStoreUrl=file:C:\Temp\application\certificate\clientkeystore.jks
&keyPassword=123456
&keyStorePassword=123456
&applicationUri=urn:8409:test:camelopcua
&applicationName=camelopcua
&node=RAW(ns=2;s=Channel2 SIMUL.SIM_1.BNAp1.18VGG1_1XA)
&samplingInterval=2000

pretty much I want to get tag value with sampling interval to 2000 ms
To understand the structure comes out from the acquisition I'm logging the body by using log camel component
log(">>> ${body}")  

I'm seeing only printed the values on the app console but I'm not getting the tag name together the value

Is there a way to add the tag name with values printed by using the keys configuration of Camel OPCUA Milo component ?
Apache Camel OPCUA Client link
